# Rotas em arquivos separados

Tags: node.js, express.js, rotas

Como coloco rotas em arquivos separados?

```
var express = require('express');
var App = express.Router();
var Notas = require('../api/notas');

App.route('/notas')
    .get(Notas.read)
    .post(Notas.create);

App.route('/notas/:id')
    .get(Notas.profile)
    .put(Notas.update)
    .delete(Notas.delete);
```

É bom separar as rotas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode separar as rotas por arquivo. Para isso crie um novo [`Router`](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/4x/api.html#router) no novo arquivo e referencie no seu arquivo principal de rotas:

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express.Router();
const notas = require('../api/notas');

app.use('/notas', notas);
```

**notas.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const get = async (req, res) => {
  res.jsonp({ mensagem: 'OK' });
}

router.get('/', get);

module.exports = router;
```

> [`Router`](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/4x/api.html#router)
>
> A router object is an isolated instance of middleware and routes. You can think of it as a "mini-application", capable only of performing middleware and routing functions. Every Express application has a built-in app router.

Em tradução livre:

> Um objeto router é uma instância isolada de middleware e rotas. Você pode pensar nisso como uma "mini aplicação", capaz apenas de realizar função de middleware e roteamento. Toda aplicação Express tem um roteador de aplicativos integrado.